# JavaScript mobile device detection

Tags: javascript

I was using the following JavaScript codes to detect either the user devices are phones or tablets (I also have to detect either the device is in portrait mode or in the landscape mode):

```
function getDeviceType() {
    if(window.innerWidth>=320 && window.innerHeight <=650) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It was working fine until we got a new Nexus 7 device and now it is not working. I am preventing to sniff the User-Agent for this for now and just want to do with the device resolutions. How can I detect if the user is using a "smart phone" (should also detect whether phone is in landscape or in portrait mode) and same for the tablets as well.

Please advice.

Comment: have you seen this one? https://github.com/barisaydinoglu/Detectizr

Comment: Describe "not working". What does `window.innerWidth` return on Nexus 7?

Comment: in Nexus 7 (in landscape mode) window.innerWidth shows 960
in portrait mode, its 600

Comment: @chris: I just checked that link but it is using two different JS libraries, don't wanna include multiple libraries just to detect the device :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why my question is down-voted. I got the solution for this problem:

```
function getDeviceType() {
    return (window.innerWidth>=320 && window.innerWidth<959) && (window.innerHeight>=212 && window.innerHeight<799) ? true : false;
}
```

This resolved the issues for the Nexus as well.